# Export Visual Studio folder structure into Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio, solution

Is there a way to export Visual Studio "Solution Explorer" structure into excel?

I tried "tree" command and clip it via Windows Command Prompt like this: [image: Like this]

but it's little hard to splite to each Excel sells.
I expecting result like this:

[image]

so any good idea for it?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: something like this? `Directory.GetFiles(path, "*").Select(x => x.Split('\\'));`

Comment: To also include files in sub-directories, type "dir /b /s > dirlist.txt" to create a list of files with the full directory structure name, such as "C:\folder\subdirectory\file.csv."

Comment: @RomanMarusyk Thanks.

Comment: @lucky125111 sry I added that I expecting.

Comment: @OleEHDufour Thanks your opinion but it has much garbage files I just wanna see like "Explorer solution"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a solution. Preety simple recursive solution to list files in the format you want

```
public class GetFilesTreeList
{
    private static List<Files> files = new List<Files>();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var path = @"C:\Users\Lukasz\Desktop";

        files.Add(new Files(Path.GetFileName(path), 0));
        WriteFilesRec(path, 1);

        foreach (var filese in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(filese);
        }

    }

    public class Files {
        public int column;
        public string name;

        public Files(string name, int column)
        {
            this.column = column;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return new String('+', column) + name; 
        }
    }

    public static void WriteFilesRec(string path, int i) {
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        foreach(var d in directory.GetDirectories()) {
            files.Add(new Files(d.Name, i));
            WriteFilesRec(Path.Combine(path, d.Name), i+1);
        }
        foreach(var f in directory.GetFiles()) {
            files.Add(new Files(f.Name, i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awsome Thanks. 
I'll customize a few things later in github.

Comment: you could instead of `files.Add()` do something like `File.Append(new String(';') + d.Name)` and write it directly to a csv file